# my database changes to Oracle to MySQL. Merge alternate in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

**Oracle query:**

```
MERGE into CMDASHBOARD x using
(
  SELECT  
    COUNT(C.CMHBASEROWKEYID_PK) count ,
    c.CLUSTERID_FK ,
    c.BAND 
  FROM CMHBASEROWKEY C 
  WHERE  (C.SICOUNT+C.NSICOUNT) = 0
    AND C.HIERARCHY = 'CELL' 
    AND TRUNC(C.MODIFIEDTIME) = TRUNC(sysdate) 
    AND C.SITETYPE != 'SMALL_CELL'
  GROUP by c.CLUSTERID_FK , c.BAND
) y on( x.CLUSTERID_FK = y.CLUSTERID_FK and x.BAND=y.band )
when matched then UPDATE set x.SECTORCOMPLIANTCOUNT = y.count 
                  WHERE TRUNC(x.CREATEDDATE) = TRUNC(sysdate);
```

**I have tried this:**

```
insert into CMDASHBOARD (SECTORCOMPLIANTCOUNT) 
  select COUNT(s.CMHBASEROWKEYID_PK) count, s.CLUSTERID_FK, s.BAND 
  from CMHBASEROWKEY s 
  JOIN CMDASHBOARD p ON p.CLUSTERID_FK= s.CLUSTERID_FK and p.BAND=s.band 
  where (s.SICOUNT+s.NSICOUNT)=0 
    AND s.HIERARCHY ='CELL' 
    AND s.SITETYPE != 'SMALL_CELL' 
    AND s.MODIFIEDTIME=sysdate() 
  GROUP by s.CLUSTERID_FK ,s.BAND;
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SECTORCOMPLIANTCOUNT= summ;
```

Comment: i TRY thisinsert into CMDASHBOARD (SECTORCOMPLIANTCOUNT)
select COUNT(s.CMHBASEROWKEYID_PK) count,
s.CLUSTERID_FK,
s.BAND
from CMHBASEROWKEY s
JOIN CMDASHBOARD p
ON p.CLUSTERID_FK=  s.CLUSTERID_FK  and p.BAND=s.band 
where (s.SICOUNT+s.NSICOUNT)=0 AND s.HIERARCHY ='CELL' AND s.SITETYPE != 'SMALL_CELL'  AND s.MODIFIEDTIME=sysdate() 
GROUP by s.CLUSTERID_FK ,s.BAND;
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  SECTORCOMPLIANTCOUNT= summ;

Comment: please next time update the question with that new information  don't comment it

Comment: MySQL's UPSET command INSERT INTO..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is the best way to replace Oracle´s UPSET command MERGE... but you should share tables and example data so that we can help you

Comment: I notice you have a semicolon `;` in the MySQL query before `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. The semicolon is end of the statement, so the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part is not part of this statement.

Comment: I've formatted your request and added the query you have shown in your comment. Next time you should do this yourself, please. Do you notice that you haven't asked a question? You say "I tried this. ...", but you don't say that and why you are not satisfied with it. Did you get a syntax error? Unwanted results? My sympathy for you for having to change from Oracle to MySQL by the way.